# Trying to expand working code to read multiple JPGs instead of just one into a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to read in a whole directory into one tensor, with each file in the directory a 28x28 image that is flattened into one row, with each new row representing another image (images are titled 0001.jpg, etc). I have been able to successfully do this for one image but have had no luck creating any loop mechanism to load the files.

I realize this is probably a simple solution but I have no clue how to go about it. If anyone has an example to point me to, or any help would be incredibly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("C:/train_data/*.jpg")
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image_orig = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
images = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
images = tf.reshape(images, [-1, 784])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    image_tensor = sess.run([images]) 
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load multiple images into the same tensor, you can use [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch). For example, to combine 32 images—which must have the same dimensions—into a single tensor, you can modify your program as follows:

```
filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("C:/train_data/*.jpg")
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image_orig = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
images = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)

# `image_batch` contains 32 consecutive images, packed into a single tensor.
image_batch, = tf.train.batch((images,), 32)
```

If your images might have different sizes, you can use an [image-processing function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image) like [`tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_image_with_crop_or_pad) to convert each `image` to the same shape before passing it to `tf.train.batch()`.

Comment: Great, this makes a lot of sense. Thank you. Getting one error along with it after adding that in. I tried creating a tf.placeholder for image_batch but that didn't seem to work.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ReadIn.py", line 18, in <module>
    image_batch = tf.train.batch(images, 32)
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.

Comment: Apologies! I forgot that `tf.train.batch()` takes a sequence of tensors. I updated the answer with a quick fix.